# iOS 7 UISearchBar UISearchBarIconSearch

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar

I am having an issue with iOS 7.

The code

```
[searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_search"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

brings different icon sizes on iOS 6 and iOS 7.

The image size is 29x29 and 58x58@2x and under iOS 6 it's displayed properly, but in iOS 7 it's twice or even more times smaller.

What could be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 6):

this seems to work for me:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_search"];
[[UIImageView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 6):

To customize `UISearchBarIconSearch` you need the following code:

```
[yourSearchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"yourImage.png"]
           forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch
                      state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To properly change the icon the resolution image must be exactly: **14x14, 28x28 for @2x and 42x42 for @3x**.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

After facing some problems with UISearchBar in iOS 7, I decided to switch to UITextField due to the placeholder text alignment.

But I still managed to get it work by setting the image for UISearchBar and it's textfield.

```
UITextField *textfieldField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_search"] 
           forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch    
           state:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *whatSearchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_search.png"];
UIImageView *whatSearchView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 29, 29)];
whatSearchView.image = whatSearchImage;
textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
textfield.leftView = whatSearchView;
```

Funny thing, if you don't set the image for the UISearchBarIcon it will use the default one from Apple but make it big.

I would also like to see if someone has found a better solution for this.

Comment: don't know if it's the best solution, but it works like a charm

Comment: How would you switch the view on one side when the mode is different? Example: you want a certain image on the `rightView` when the mode is `whileEditing`, and you want a different image for the same `rightView` when the mode is `unlessEditing` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then I made size for search icon smaller and everything is ok now.

Play with icon size.

E.g. I changed size of retina image from 38x38 to 30x30, and now it works perfect. Probably iOS checks size and if it is not proper it uses instead of retina non-retina image

Comment: Mine worked on a 40x40 retina image resolution on iOS 7.